# Is Enterprise Library still being updated?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, enterprise-library

I'll be porting an asp.net website in Net 2.0 to a more recent version of .Net 4.5.

I'm looking for more modern libraries to use for SQL Server connectivity, and I noticed that the last update for Enterprise Library was done in April 2013.

Is Enterprise Library still being used or is there something newer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [CodePlex project page for Enterprise Library](http://entlib.codeplex.com/) (which goes read-only Nov 6, 2017) says:

> This project is no longer under development.
>
> Unity has new ownership and has [relocated to GitHub](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/08/21/the-future-of-unity/).
>   The remainder of
>   the application blocks will no longer be developed. However, the
>   source will continue to be available. We encourage any interested
>   parties to fork the source as desired.

So, other than Unity it's looking pretty dead.  It's unclear if MS will be keeping read-only CodePlex online or not.

Comment: Thanks. What's being used now for sql server connectivity? Is there anything that replaces Enterprise Library?

Comment: @rbhat I don't know the answer to that.  I'm a DBA who found the answer by trying to figure out what Enterprise Library was.